# Issue capturing images an set into imageView into Samsung devices

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

When i capture images through device camera and set bitmap into imageView,why image rotate into Samsung device only and   in rest of the devices work fine.

my code is:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, timeStamp);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    imageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

and the onActivityResult is:

```
try
            {
                thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                selfie.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: 1) Post code you used to take image and display image. 2) Use an image loading library (e.g. Fresco) that handles orientation EXIF tags for you.

Comment: String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, timeStamp);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
        imageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

Comment: thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    selfieImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

in onActivityResult

Comment: Please edit your question and put formatted code in there, never in comments.